# Reinitialize matterjs after page changes in nuxtjs

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, matter.js

I have a [matterjs](https://brm.io/matter-js/) instance in my nuxt app that drops items on the floor. Everything works when I visit the page for the first time or do a page refresh. But when I change the pages (routes) inside my app, so I come back to the page with the matterjs instance, the instance is gone. I always have to do a page refresh...

How can I reinitialize matterjs?

**Fallbox**

```html
<section class="fallbox">
    <div class="fallbox-content">
      <nuxt-link to="/"><h1>Index</h1></nuxt-link>
    </div>
    <div class="fallbox-scene">
      <div v-for="item in items" :key="item.className">
        <span :class="item.className" class="item"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          className: "-i1",
        },
        {
          className: "-i2",
        },
        {
          className: "-i3",
        },
        {
          className: "-i4",
        },
        {
          className: "-i5",
        },
      ],
    };
  },

  mounted() {
    window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
      this.startFallbox();
    });
  },

  methods: {
    startFallbox() {
      const Engine = Matter.Engine;
      const Render = Matter.Render;
      const Runner = Matter.Runner;
      const Bodies = Matter.Bodies;
      const Body = Matter.Body;
      const Composite = Matter.Composite;
      const MouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint;

      const engine = Engine.create();
      const world = engine.world;
      engine.gravity.y = 1;

      const fallbox = document.querySelector(".fallbox-scene");

      const render = Render.create({
        element: fallbox,
        engine,
        options: {
          width: fallbox.offsetWidth,
          height: fallbox.offsetHeight,
        },
      });

      // Render.run(render);

      const runner = Runner.create();
      Runner.run(runner, engine);

      const itemArray = this.items;
      itemArray.forEach((i) => {
        const get = document.getElementsByClassName(i.className)[0];

        get.style.opacity = 1;

        const item = {
          w: get.clientWidth,
          h: get.clientHeight,
          body: Bodies.rectangle(
            Math.random() * window.innerWidth,
            Math.random() * -1000,
            get.clientWidth,
            get.clientHeight,
            {
              restitution: 0.5,
              angle: Math.random() * 360,
            }
          ),

          elem: get,
          render() {
            const { x, y } = this.body.position;
            this.elem.style.top = `${y - this.h / 2}px`;
            this.elem.style.left = `${x - this.w / 2}px`;
            this.elem.style.transform = `rotate(${this.body.angle}rad)`;
          },
        };

        Body.rotate(item.body, Math.random() * 360);

        Composite.add(world, [item.body]);

        (function rerender() {
          item.render();
          requestAnimationFrame(rerender);
        })();
      });

      const ground = Bodies.rectangle(
        fallbox.offsetWidth / 2,
        fallbox.offsetHeight,
        2000,
        1,
        {
          isStatic: true,
        }
      );

      const left = Bodies.rectangle(
        0,
        fallbox.offsetHeight / 2,
        1,
        fallbox.offsetHeight,
        {
          isStatic: true,
        }
      );

      const right = Bodies.rectangle(
        fallbox.offsetWidth,
        fallbox.offsetHeight / 2,
        1,
        fallbox.offsetHeight,
        {
          isStatic: true,
        }
      );

      Composite.add(world, [ground, left, right]);

      const mouseConstraint = MouseConstraint.create(engine, {
        element: fallbox,
        constraint: {
          stiffness: 0.2,
        },
      });

      mouseConstraint.mouse.element.removeEventListener(
        "mousewheel",
        mouseConstraint.mouse.mousewheel
      );
      mouseConstraint.mouse.element.removeEventListener(
        "DOMMouseScroll",
        mouseConstraint.mouse.mousewheel
      );

      Composite.add(world, mouseConstraint);

      Render.lookAt(render, {
        min: { x: 0, y: 0 },
        max: { x: fallbox.offsetWidth, y: fallbox.offsetHeight },
      });
    },
  },
};
```

```css
.fallbox {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;

  .fallbox-content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: 95%;
    max-width: 1050px;
    z-index: 2;

    // -khtml-user-select: none;
    // -moz-user-select: none;
    // -ms-user-select: none;
    // user-select: none;
    // pointer-events: none;

    h1 {
      font-size: 160px;
      font-weight: 500;
      line-height: 140px;
      margin-bottom: 150px;
      text-align: center;
      color: white;
    }
  }

  .fallbox-scene {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    contain: strict;

    .item {
      height: 120px;
      width: 120px;
      background: red;
      position: absolute;
      opacity: 0;
      user-select: none;
      will-change: transform;

      -khtml-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't much information to work off of. If anyone does write an answer, it'll likely not be way off-target for your use case or require a lot of guesswork and adaptation on your part to work. If you provide a [mcve], then it becomes much easier to help.

Comment: Looking for this kind of event listener is probably a bad idea. You should rather give us your matterjs code so that we can see what is not working there. There is probably a `trigger` or some kind of method to re-run the whole thing without the need to nuke your SPA (never an actual solution).

Answer (score 0):

```js
activated() {
  this.startFallbox()
}
```

Use the activated hook to restart the animation. The code when mounted() is still needed.

I assume the problem is that when you navigate away and you some back the initial animation is finished, but as Nuxt caches some pages they are served from cache and therefore the mounted() hook is not called. This is where the activated() hooks comes in. It's called when a page/component was keept alive and is reactivated.

Comment: Nuxt doesn't cache all lifecycles etc.., the `mounted()` hook totally re-runs upon navigation. Overall, I'm not sure `activated()` is the reason here.

Comment: Thanks! Activated() hasn't helped. I finally published a simplified version of my code.